# Cannot force reload page in vercel production (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm implementing midtrans snap api to handle transaction in my project. When i trigger a button that call the snap api suddenly i got an error like this:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

I realize when i refresh the page manually, the button works and give me the midtrans snap UI to handle online transaction. So i'm using workaround to make the page refresh once when it got loaded using window.location.reload / router.reload and it works just fine in develpoment (local server).

But when i'm deploying it to vercel, the error shows again and i think that's because the window.location.reload / router.reload doesn't triggered in production.

Any one have faces this issues? i'm searching for hour but still got no solution